# Where is protoc and how do i install it?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'd like to use the `protoc` command to generate java files

I've been following the instructions in the README from github https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf but it just tells you to download the zip file and that the "binary" is already included. However, after downloading the latest (and a couple other versions) and unzipping the files, I can't find the "protoc" binary.

Is there some other missing instruction that i'm supposed to follow?

P.S. i'm using Mac OS X

Comment: There seems to be no proper build for JAVA on Mac OS as per this page.https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf

Comment: See : https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3490 - btw, I also host an online runnable build of protoc on my site here: https://protogen.marcgravell.com

Answer (score 3):

Open https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases and look for the binary for 32- or 64-bit OS X:

- protoc-3.6.1-osx-x86_32.zip
- protoc-3.6.1-osx-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had to install it using homebrew

something like this answer: [Installing Google Protocol Buffers on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775151/installing-google-protocol-buffers-on-mac)