# Cannot install php extension 'mysql_xdevapi' on mac

Tags: macos, php-extension, mysql-x-devapi

When I run `pecl install mysql_xdevapi` in the terminal I get the following error:

> configure: error: protobuf not found, please install it in system, consider use of --with-protobuf or setting MYSQL_XDEVAPI_PROTOBUF_ROOT

I then installed 'protobuf' via `brew install protobuf`. Running `protoc --version` gives me:

> libprotoc 3.12.4

So it seems like 'protobuf' is installed. When I then run `pecl install mysql_xdevapi` again I get the same error that tells me 'protobuf' is not installed. I've tried pretty much everything I found in this post: [Installing Google Protocol Buffers on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21775151/5371227) but nothing seems to work.

I'm running macOS Catalina (10.15.6), PHP 7.3.20 (installed via `brew`).

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its to late, but after spending around six hours of my time on this I finally managed it to work. Apparently there is a bug in pecl package, so we must things by our hands.

If you really sure you have protobuf installed than continue or install it beforehand
First you need to download package

```
pecl download mysql_xdevapi
```

Unzip a package and cd to unzipped directory

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/include/php/mysql_xdevapi-8.0.26
```

You will see a folder and an XML file, cd to folder

```
cd mysql_xdevapi-8.0.26/
```

and locate file named config.m4. Find this line, it should be line number 416 but may vary

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER("google/protobuf/any.h", [], [PROTOBUF_INCLUDES_NOT_FOUND=1])
```

and change it to that

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER("google/protobuf/any.h", [], [PROTOBUF_INCLUDES_NOT_FOUND1=1])
```

then run

```
sudo phpize
```

what we just did is created a configure file for us
now run created configure

```
./configure
```

Configuration should finish without errors

than run

```
make
make install
```

that's it!

Don't forget to add extension to php ini

```
extension="mysql_xdevapi.so"
```