# Where to find protobuf@3.6?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-python, cld3

My python gcld3 package broke recently because it is linked against libprotobuf.30.dylib and a recent homebrew update replaced this lib with a newer version.

The package protobuf@3.6 has libprotobuf.30.dylib but Homebrew disabled it.

- Do you know where I could find libprotobuf.30.dylib?
- If you still have it on your machine, can you please share it via a link?

Answer (score 0):

`protobuf@3.6` can be installed by editing `protobuf@3.6.rb` in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula`
After moving the deprecation date to the future, the formula still works fine.
But protobuf@3.6 has libprotobuf.17.dylib, so to get `libprotobuf.30.dylib` I had to install protobuf 3.19 from the source.

Following the steps of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23224953/1031191,
and downloading protobuf 3.19.2 from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.19.2/protobuf-all-3.19.2.tar.gz
I could successfully install the protobuf on MacOS Catalina that is compatible with `gcld3==3.0.13`.